# Does converse statement hold in Complete spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So my notes say that a normed space is complete if every cauchy sequence with respect to the norm is convergent.     Does the converse hold? Is every convergent sequence with respect to the norm also a cauchy sequence?

Comment: That’s simply the definition of completeness: a normed linear space is by definition complete if and only if every Cauchy sequence with respect to the norm converges.

Comment: Ok great thanks. Was just wondering as I was only shown one direction, I guess the converse is easy to prove once you have done the other direction.

Comment: There’s no need to prove anything: it really is just a definition. It’s like saying that an integer is even if it is a multiple of $2$. That’s just a definition of *even* and could just as well read that an integer is even if and only if it’s a multiple of $2$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention.  I was talking about a proof in my notes showing that space of bounded continuous functions with the supremum norm is complete, but he just showed one direction.

Comment: Yes, every convergent sequence is Cauchy - this holds in incomplete spaces too. It's worth trying to prove for yourself.

Comment: @user771918 ok thanks I understand now, the proof was straightforward. So the reason he only proved one direction in my notes is that we already know that every convergent sequence is Cauchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every convergent sequence is Cauchy is true in any metric space. And this is a very good question. Cauchy-ness is the essence of convergence in metric spaces, and it makes sense -- if the tail of a sequence land in an arbitrarily small cluster, then it should converge somewhere. You can think of it this way: all convergent sequences are Cauchy; all Cauchy sequences "want to converge", and if it doesn't it means there's a "hole" in the space. What's really nice about it is that these holes can be filled up. If you consider the set of all Cauchy sequences in a metric space, and declare the equivalence relationship that $\{ x_n\} \sim \{ y_n \}$ if the sequence $\{z_n\} = \{d(x_n, y_n)\}$ converges to $0$ in $\mathbb R$. The space of the equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences under this equivalence relation is the completion of the original space, which is indeed complete! Points in the original space are represented by the constant sequences. It is a good example to see that $\mathbb R$ is the completion of $\mathbb Q$, which is also a nice way to see that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: great thanks,/space so o show a space is not complete, is it enough to show that there is a sequence of elements from that space that converges to an element that is not part of that space.
e.g to show the space C[0,1] is not complete with respect to the 2 norm, can we find a sequence of continuous functions that converge (w.r.t the norm) to a discontinuous function.